# PL SQL CASE WHEN statement

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, case-when

I am looking to find a way to write a CASE WHEN statement that returns a value if ANY of the items = a specific criteria.  Here is a little background:

I have transactions that have several different assets on each transaction and those assets could all have different suppliers associated with them.  I am aggregating the data to a transaction level and I am looking to flag the transactions where ANY asset on the transaction has a supplier that is the same as the customer on that transaction.

So if any supplier from all the assets on transaction X equals the customer on transaction X flag this deal

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Case _expression_...

Comment: Why PL SQL? This sounds like SQL to me. If it has anything to do with PL/SQL, please clarify.

Comment: The title of the question is unclear of what you intend to do. Please rephrase it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists`.  Without sample data and desired results, it is a little tricky to form the entire query, but something like this:

```
select t.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from suppliers s where t.customer = s.supplier)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as flag
from transactions t;
```